# Create a MATLAB matrix

Tags: matlab

I want to create a matrix using `QP = [20 22 28 35 50]`

and make:

```
x = [20, 22, 28, 35, 50;
20, 22, 28, 35, 50;
20, 22, 28, 35, 50;]
```

I know how to make it manually, but I am looking for an efficient way to create such example.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [**`repmat`**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repmat.html) to repeat copies of array:

```
x = repmat(QP, 3, 1)
```

Comment: Thanks @herohuyongtao